# Upgraded project from java7 to java8 and updated maven dependency caused spring oauth2 response type changed

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, jackson, jackson-databind

I have recently upgrade my project to java 8, but encounted an issue, the inital auth request send to /oauth/token , it response is changed to structure like below:

```
{
    "value": "640b6662-15d0-495d-a3f6-85cef91f330a",
    "expiration": 1615774638214,
    "tokenType": "bearer",
    "refreshToken": {
        "value": "215a7298-674b-49b9-9ce2-e713503d5d0f",
        "expiration": 1715763837211
    },
    "scope": [
        "read",
        "trust",
        "write"
    ],
    "additionalInformation": {},
    "expiresIn": 6721,
    "expired": false
}
```

Before project upgraded, the intial /oauth/token response is something like , and this is what I expected to get :

```
{
"access_token":"523dd467-e5c0-407b-95e4-ea60a403d772",
"token_type":"bearer",
"refresh_token ":"e3378c95-1ebf-419b-bf45-e734d8e94aba",
"expires_in":43199
}
```

As this structure is crticial damage change to my mobile apps, e.g my mobile app is calling this api rely on what I expected structure like above

Wondering anyway to force change the response from new structure to old one?

Here is my setup:
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0
    com.example
    spring-hibernate-template
    war
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

```
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>               
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
        <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.47.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>newrelic-agent</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dropbox.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropbox-core-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.turo</groupId>
        <artifactId>pushy</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
      <!--<dependency>-->
         <!--<groupId>com.notnoop.apns</groupId>-->
         <!--<artifactId>apns</artifactId>-->
         <!--<version>1.0.0.Beta6</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>8.5.47.2</version>
                                <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                      <id>copy-new-relic</id>
                      <phase>package</phase>
                 <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                        <includeGroupIds>com.newrelic.agent.java</includeGroupIds>
                        <includeArtifactIds>newrelic-agent</includeArtifactIds>
                        <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And my spring security context xml config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
   xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
```

<sec:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"   />

<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
oauth:authorization-code/
oauth:implicit/
oauth:refresh-token/
oauth:client-credentials/
oauth:password/
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
resource-id="dstest"
token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">

```
<oauth:client client-id="my-trusted-client"
              authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit,redirect"
              authorities="ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT"
              redirect-uri="/web"
              scope="read,write,trust"
              access-token-validity="10800"
              refresh-token-validity="99999999"/>
```

</oauth:client-details-service>

<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
<sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
</sec:global-method-security>
<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler"/>

All I need is just to get auth reponse structure change back to old style
Any advise?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in fact, i featured this out,  just update the
spring-security-oauth2 version to :

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

it resolves my problem